# How to add CORS header to my REST API if I dont have a domain?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rest

I am working on a REST API and it runs on an extern server with an own public IP. Now I want to call it from my PC at home, which logically doesnt have an own IP or domain. How am I supposed to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin for my PC?

This is my function (I censored the API key):

```
async function loadTelluzApi(url) {

            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
              //  body: myBody, // string or object
                headers: {
                    'ApiKey': 'apikey'
                }
            });
             console.log(response.json())
            return await response.json();

    }
```

For test-purposes I added this above the controler of my REST API:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

And I get the following error:

> Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

Comment: You cannot control CORS from the requestor.  It has to be configured on the destination server.

Comment: "which logically doesnt have an own IP or domain" ... If it's connected to the internet then it will have a public IP address. Go to a site like whatismyip.com (or many others) from that machine to find out what it is. Be warned though that the IP may not stay static, domestic internet providers may not give you a permanent IP and it may change from time to time.

Comment: P.s. but then again, if you are trying to access the API via AJAX from a website which is hosted on your home PC (which is the only scenario in which CORS would be applicable to the situation you've described), then you more than likely accessed that site via `http://localhost` or similar, so you could just add that to your CORS access control header. Remember it's the domain of the website to which the restrictions apply, not the machine which made the original connection to that site

Comment: And also remember that CORS doesn't apply to non-AJAX HTTP requests. It's a bit unclear precisely what the scenario is, really. Have you actually tried to access this API from your PC and encountered a specific problem? If so please show the code you used, and the exact error message you received.

Comment: @Taplar To be fair, you _can_ have a remote system that allows for customizable CORS headers by letting an authenticated client specify the set of CORS domains for their current session/access-token/client-id. Of course the endpoint for configuring those CORS parameters itself would have to allow `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` which may or may not defeat the point of CORS.

Comment: @Dai Sure, but that again relies on the destination being configured to work that way.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to add the custom-headers in the Web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: This will allow cross-domain access from any site, not just your own. Is that ok? It removes the purpose of CORS really. Consider carefully whether you think that's an acceptable risk for your app and for your users. Depending on the purpose and functionality of the API, it might be fine. Or it might be a security hole.

Comment: For test-purposes its enough. For live environment I will put the IP of our frontend-server